# Back-end processing in chrome extension

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on a chrome extension, which I'm pretty new to.  I was wondering how exactly I can execute operations in this extension without having to host my own server.  Basically, I'm trying to build an app that is going to interface with another website's API.  The Google documents talk about how I can use html, css, and javascript in my extension, but in order to interface with this API, I would need to use something like PHP (which I know) or ruby (which I don't).  But PHP only executes server side.  It seems pointless to host a server just to do that, it should be possible to do client side.  So basically, what's the procedure for building code (not HTML, CSS, or JS) to execute client side in a chrome extension, whether that be for working with an API or just for general processing?  Languages like Java and Python work for this API too (not JS) but that seems like it would be more difficult to then reintegrate the information they return into the displayed HTML/CSS.

Sorry if that's a rambling question, I'm really new to this.  Thanks in advance

Comment: It _is_ a rambling question. Not knowing anything about the API you mentioned, we cannot hope to help in a concrete fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, You won't be able to use PHP, Ruby or Java in the browser. You can only use JavaScript.
Why do you need server side client for the API? You may can do your call with JavaScript ? Otherwise you will need a sever.

Comment: The API isn't written for JS.  So unless there's a way to interface with a PHP (or Ruby, or Java) API through JS that doesn't involve contacting a server, I guess I'm gonna need to host something.

Comment: Looks like I may have been wrong, I think there is a JS version, it just wasn't listed on the main page for some reason...

Comment: I hope that you'll find what you need to advance